# Compositing - Final scene renders fine first and in a last step black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes

I try to render a composition in cycles based on motion tracked footage. When I press Shift-Z for render preview everything is fine. But when I hit the render button in the render tab it renders fine first, but in a last step all tiles change to black. The result looks like a scene without light.

[image]

I played around with the render layers, but without success.

@cegaton: thank you for the note, here comes a screenshot of the node editor, that was set up automatically. I'm learning blender for a few weeks now and this is my first attempt to compositing.

[image]

Does someone have a idea what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how you set up the scene in the compositor. Please use the [edit] link under your question and add an image of the node tree as part of the question.

Comment: Sorry for the missing screenshot, it's included in my post now.

Comment: See in the two *Render Layer* nodes, how all of your objects are black. That means that they really are rendering black. In this case the compositor is not the issue. Could be your lights are not rendering or you might have a override material on the renderlayer that is all black.

Comment: Please add an image of the material nodes.

Comment: I want to thank you for your efforts, but I think it makes much more sense for me to learn more about this topic and to start the scene from scratch than to let all of you search a mistake I made. I think I messed the scene up with different imported models and old and new materials ...